# Query to find under which range given value fall in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement where I have to find the price range

We have to send a parameter via a stored procedure like (5, 10, 15, etc..)

If we send 5 as a parameter

```
Price   Range
--------------
2       1-5
3       1-5
20      15-20
12      11-15 etc..
```

If we send 10 as a parameter

```
Price   Range
--------------
2       1-10
3       1-10
20      11-20
12      11-20 etc.
```

I have tried many ways, but not working.
Anyone help me how to write a query for the above requirement

Answer (score 4):

Simply use arithmetic:

```
select t.price,
       concat( floor(price / @param) * @param, '-', (floor(price / @param) + 1) * @param)
from t
```

This will actually give 0-10, rather than 1-10.  But that is more consistent with the other ranges.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8df87b2e2a8ce74a8a8a34df24e996f5) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  I would recommend having ranges whose names do not overlap -- '0-9', '10-19', and so on.  However, that is not the question that you have asked here.